# Matrix input (multi-dimensional) Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: probability, machine-learning, covariance, gaussian

In the book GPML (http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf), input is $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Stacking $N$ such inputs, i.e. $X = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_N
\end{pmatrix}^T$ results in $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times d}$. Given the training output $Y$ of appropriate dimension,

$$Y \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mathbf{0}, K)$$

where $K \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is the covariance matrix. Now, depending on the choice of kernel function, $k(p, q)$, it can essentially be written as

$$k: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

where ${p, q}$ represent the indices.

**My question:** For $N$ matrix inputs $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$, this is how I think the stacking would be done, i.e. $X = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_N
\end{pmatrix}^T$, like block matrices which results in $X \in \mathbb{R}^{Nn \times d}$. Again, following the theme,

$$Y \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mathbf{0}, K)$$

What dimension should $K$ be?

- If the kernel function is about relating **inputs** to each other, then the covariance matrix is given by $K \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and the kernel function $k(p,q)$ defines a mapping

$$k: \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

relating the $N$ inputs to each other.

- If the kernel function is about relating **indices** to each other, then $K \in \mathbb{R}^{Nn \times Nn}$ characterized by kernel function $k(p,q)$ defines a mapping

$$k: \mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

relating the $Nn$ indices (similar to the vector input case) to each other.

- Or should I approach the stacking in $X$ differently, i.e. $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times d \times n}$, a third order tensor?

If my question is unclear please let me know and I can add necessary information. Please feel free to point out any obvious mistakes.

Comment: When I needed to solve a similar problem and I wanted a Gaussian Process on matrices, I considered each row (or column) independent on each other and approximate each row (or column) using a (vector) Gaussian Process

Comment: @A.Pesare Can you give me an example from somewhere? Do you mean $X = (x_1 \: \ldots \: x_n)^T$ and $Y = (y_1 \: \ldots \: y_n)^T$ where $y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K(x_i, x'_i))$? How fair was this assumption of independence between the columns? Do you assume a rank constraint?

Comment: @A.Pesare The main thing I want to understand is how the construction of covariance function is done? Suppose there are $N$ inputs i.e. $X_i$ with $i \in {1, \ldots, N}$. Do you define a covariance function corresponding to columns $y_j$ in $Y$ i.e. $y_j \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K(x_j, x'_j))$ and the kernel function is a mapping: $k(x_j, x'_j): \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $x_j$ and $x'_j$ are the $i^{th}$ columns taken from the $N$ different inputs $X_i$?

Comment: Edit: $j^{th}$ column of input $X_i$ and not $i^{th}$ column

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_multivariate_linear_regression) they use the Kronecker product of matrices. If you understand this, it is a really good reading.